# Are Collection MetaClasses different from other MetaClasses?

Tags: groovy, collections, metaprogramming

[As this image shows](https://i.gyazo.com/4598ceea6ce34adf872ad396b6515306.png), I can get a MetaMethod from the String and other MetaClasses, but IDEA says that it cannot resolve "getMetaMethod" for the Collection or the List MetaClasses and it returns null.

Is the Collection MetaClass different from other Object MetaClasses?

Edit: Here is the code

```
def listToString = List.metaClass.getMetaMethod("toString", null)
def collectionToString = Collection.metaClass.getMetaMethod("toString", null)

def stringToString = String.metaClass.getMetaMethod("toString", null)
def objectToString = Object.metaClass.getMetaMethod("toString", null)
def integerToString = Integer.metaClass.getMetaMethod("toString", null)

println listToString
println collectionToString
println stringToString
println objectToString
println integerToString
```

Comment: They're the same, it's a bug in IDEA.